# Rusted gas pipe elbows on new house

Tags: natural-gas

The gas connection into my new house (less than a year old) was heavily painted but the paint is peeling revealing rusted and pitted pipe, especially the elbow pipe.  Also, the gas pipe connection for a gas barbeque is not painted and is very rusted and pitted.  What should I do about this?  Should I contact the builder and require a replacement of the rusted pipes?

Comment: Welcome to DIYSE. The question as you've asked it is a matter of opinion, and therefore [not a good fit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this network. You might revise to ask how to repair the situation instead. If you do, photos are almost a necessity for this question.

Comment: That pipe is very thick and the most that would be required would be wire brushing and painting. Definitely replacement is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Gas pipe is usually ductile iron pipe, not galvanized, because the galvanizing can flake off and clog gas fittings. So not being protected with the zinc coating, it rusts. It will likely take decades to become rusted through enough to become a problem however and as mentioned, a simple wire brush cleaning and new paint will prolong its life greatly.

Comment: Agreed just pick up a can of paint and put cardboard behind it and paint it. In all the years I've been dealing with gas I've only run into two perforated pipes and they were at least 50 years old. We are talking about literally at least tens of miles of pipe.